# Replacing / with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a question regarding replacing some characters with regex or any other best practice or efficient way.
Here is what I have as input, it has mostly the same form: `A/ABC/N/ABC/123`
The output should look like this: `A_ABC_NABC123`, basically the first 2 `/` should be changed to `_` and the rest removed.
Of course i could do with some `String.Replace`. etc one by one, but I don't think it is a good way to do that. I search for a better solution.

So how to do it with Regex?

Comment: Replace is fine for what you need here, it is faster (as it doesn't have to parse the regex), see here http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/419168-Which-one-is-faster-RegEx-vs-Replace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it, although there may be a simpler way:

```
static class CustomReplacer
{
    public static string Replace(string input)
    {
        int i = 0;
        return Regex.Replace(input, "/", m => i++ < 2 ? "_" : "");
    }
}

var replaced = CustomReplacer.Replace("A/ABC/N/ABC/123");
```

I've wrapped the code like this to make sure you don't accidentally the `int` variable.

Edit: There's also [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) which stops after a certain number of replacements, but you'd have to do it in two steps: replace the first two `/` with `_`, then replace the remaining `/` with nothing.

Comment: you have made it too complicated..;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string st = "A/ABC/N/ABC/123";
string [] arrStr = st.Split(new char[] { '/' });
st = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < 2)
        st += arrStr[i] + "_";
    else
        st += arrStr[i];
}
```